# boost::atomic compile issues

Tags: c++, boost, atomic

I know that `boost::atomic` isn't an official part of the boost library, but I've seen it referred to a number of times on stackoverflow, so thought I'd give it a go. I should prefice this post by saying that I have searched google, stackoverflow and the documentation for `boost::atomic` before posting this.

I downloaded `boost::atomic` from http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/ and copied it into my boost folder. However, I'm having issues with it actually compiling after being included and I think there's an error in the code. One of the functions that is causing issues is this

```
static inline void
                platform_fence_after_load(memory_order)
            {
                if (order == memory_order_seq_cst()) {
                    x86_full_fence(void);
                }
            }
```

The first issue is that `order` isn't defined, `memory_order_seq_cst` isn't a function and `x86_full_fence` shouldn't have void as a parameter. It's easy enough to fix those errors, but I'm not sure if they're a symptom of something else. Has anyone here used `boost::atomic` before? Is it stable, and does it work correctly? Finally, are these actually issues with `boost::atomic` or am I simply not using it correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used it for a long time it is quite stable but it have some problems in header `interlocked.hpp`, one of issues is addressed by you and it is quite easy to solve it and other is one function is not declared as `inline`, so it will generate a linker error, but after solving them AFAIK it really work without any problem